# How to create an id for a vertical navigation menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a simple vertical menu that I am creating. The problem is, I'd like to put this menu under a single 'id' called #menu so that I can move it around, instead of moving each individual link.

Here is the code for my menu:

```
<ul>
<li> <a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
<li> <a href="#Business">Business</a></li>
<li> <a href="#About">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

How do I get all of this info under the 'id' #menu, so that I can just manipulate #menu and move the navigational links around, without having to change either 'li' or 'a'?

Comment: give the ul an Id???

Comment: <ul id="myid"> <li></li></ul>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be missing something, but this is what i understand you want:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li> <a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
<li> <a href="#Business">Business</a></li>
<li> <a href="#About">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What if I had 3 separate links that were not contained in a list, how could I bunch them all together under one ID?

Comment: like the guy above said, that would be a class. IDs are unique while classes should be reused.

Comment: Ok, I have 3 separate links. I used DIV to separate the 3. How do I turn the DIV into a class, so that the class now becomes the DIV, and I am able to manipulate the 3 links using only the class in CSS?

Comment: yes you are. And turning a div into a class is as simple as adding a class to a div ;) `<div class="some_class and_another_maybe"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

wrap in a nav element.

```
<nav class="menu" ></nav>
```

Comment: IMHO it is bad practice to assume that `<nav>` will be the only `<nav>` as you are supposed to wrap any navs in it (Like top, sidebar, footer). I still would add a id or class for identification.

Comment: What if I had 3 separate links that were not contained in a list, how could I bunch them all together under one ID?

Comment: you would use a class

Comment: better to use class for styling and leave ids for use with JavaScript

Comment: except for anchors and defining sections for SEO purposes ;)